# Determine significance of an observed continuous distribution given many randomly generated continuous distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, sampling

Suppose there is a vector, `v`, that contains the body height of every person over 30 years old on earth. It looks something like this: `[ 1.5, 1.8, 1.3 ... ]` and is normally distributed.

Also suppose there is simple function, `f`, that takes as input a vector, `i`. This vector has index positions that correspond to positions in `v` (which correspond to individuals' heights). As output, `f` gives back another vector, `h`, which contains height values from `v` corresponding to index positions in `i`.

Now let's say there is a list of `n` peoples' heights and the goal is to find out whether this 'observed sample' is significantly taller or shorter than the rest of the people in the world.

One way to do this would be randomly generate many index position vectors of size `n` and feed them to `f`. Doing this would produce the following:

```
Random distribution set: [ [rand-dist1], [rand-dist2]  ... ]
Observed distribution: [obs-dist]
```

My question is: **Given the observed distribution and the random set of distributions (all are continuous), what is the best way to determine whether the observed distribution is significantly different than what one would expect given the set of random distributions?**